# Javascript library or framework for drawing charts on client side

Tags: javascript, graph, javascript-framework, jqplot

I'm looking for an library, to generate charts on client side.
I found a lot, by searching on web and stackoverflow, like here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227421/good-javascript-library-for-drawing-charts-using-json

or this very good collection:

http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/20-fresh-javascript-data-visualization-libraries/

There are so much alternatives, I'm a bit overwhelmed. Which one can use JSON data, which one is up to date, which one is easy to use (because I'm absolutely new on this topic), which one is robust, works on mobile phone (or not), which project is still alive, etc.

I need different chards, an line chart is mandatory. Also zoom in and zoom out is mandatory.
So I took a closer look on jqplot an flot.

Both providing zoom, but it looks like zooming is more an scaling. Which means: the granularity will not change by zoom in.
Because the graph will have a lot of data/points, i need to consolidate informations before sending them to the client. By zooming in, I need to rise the granularity, so the chart should be able to process new data for the zoomed area. (I hope I've made ​​myself clear.)

Thanks for any kind of attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no helpful answer, so I like to write down, what i learned the last days for this question.

jqPlot and frot are supporting zooming at an basic level. That means, it's more an scaling.
By looking at the google groups for qjPlot and flot, the support for jqPlot is better (lot's of unanswered questions at the flot group).
jqPlot has an better axis-label-handling by zooming.
jqPlot also provides hooks. By using those hooks, it's seems to be possible to combine zooming and loading new JSON data in order to get an better granularity of the zoomed view.

Answer (score 1):

Raphael.js http://raphaeljs.com/

HTML5 Graph http://chrisvalleskey.com/html5-graph/

Google Visualization API: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html

Flot: http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: are those 4 frameworks/plugins supporting zoom by loading/processing new, granular data for that zoomed view?

Comment: imho flot supported zooming few years go